# Why does this Windows icon looks like a Trojan?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus

Why did Windows designed such a strange icon? When you look at it, you easily think of the Trojans, because you can see a horse at the screen. Here's the picture (the image source is the Scheme compiler installer [Petite Chez Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/download/index.html#sec:petitechezscheme)):

[image]

- Are here special reasons for Windows to design such a trojan-like icon?
- When I was uninstalling Petite Chez Scheme, my Anti-virus software warned me it was attempting to modify my environment variable. I chose to reject its action and I uninstalled it successfully.
- Is Petite Chez Scheme really a Trojan?

Comment: This icon?http://note.youdao.com/yws/public/resource/8c4101c64cdeb772ae156e089d0601a3/A73C0B26BB2647CF852AB8F781B7E9B9

Comment: I have no idea if this is a trojan, but you appear to be taking the icon too seriously. its just pretending the user is looking at pictures of horses. 'OMG Ponies!'

Comment: Why do you think this icon is from Microsoft? Icons are taken out of the `.exe` file and are designed (or taken from other sources) by the maker of the program. The normal icon of an Microsoft install does not have the 'horse in the screen'.

Comment: @FrankThomas How dare you call the Winamp Llama a pony?

Comment: mea culpa. it is too bad that winamp is being retired. it was always my favorite in windows. didn't try to be more than it should, worked fine with smb shares, didn't try to copy everything to the local user profile before indexing, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It's the icon for old versions of the NSIS installer.

---

***What does this Windows icon mean?***

The image is the icon for older versions of the Nullsoft Scriptable Install System, an installer created by the Winamp team:

> Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS) is a script-driven
>   installation system for Microsoft Windows with minimal overhead backed
>   by Nullsoft, the creators of Winamp. NSIS has become a widely used
>   alternative to commercial and proprietary products like InstallShield,
>   with users including Amazon, Dropbox, Ubisoft, BitTorrent, and McAfee.

-- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System)

***Is there special reasons for Windows to design such a trojan-like ico?***

Windows does not design anything, Windows is a product created by Microsoft. Microsoft does design products and features, but only for its products. This icon is not for a Microsoft product.

Also, it is in no way trojan-related, and the image isn't even a horse: it is a llama, the Winamp mascot:

[image]

(It really whips the llama's ass!)

***When I was uninstalling [software], my Anti-virus software warned me it was attempting to modify environment variables***

It is perfectly normal for installers and uninstallers to modify system variables in order to, I. E., add / remove itself from starting at boot, creating file associations, etc etc.

***Is [software] really a Trojan?***

There is no definite way of knowing, but checking it on [VirusTotal](http://virustotal.com/) might help.

Comment: I would wonder what AV would be paranoid enough to complain its modifying environmental variables. A *lot* of software does this, especially path. I'd add that with a little more context, it does look legit - programming language compilers/interpreters *do* need to muck with environmental variables , and most of what I can find about it, especially on wikipedia seems to make it look legitimate. And yes, that is a illama, and NSIS is a VERY common installer thats used a lot, and they often use that same default icon

Comment: Llamas!!! Meeeaaagh!